Streamlit-folium no data return on click
Using streamlit_folium and geopandas explore() to display a choropleth map drawn with this code:
m = my_shapefile.explore(
    column = 'risk',
    popup = ['ID_PARCEL', 'Risk of infection:'],
    tooltip = 'Risk of infection:',        
)


st_data = st_folium(m, width = 800, height = 500)
st.write(st_data) 

It seems that st_data never gets updated when clicking on elements of the map:

I tried repeating st.write(st_data) every second to see if there was any update that was not displayed, but I had the same result whether I click on polygons or not.

Seems like a bug to me and has to do with the column parameter of explore.

That is strange, the column I passed has nothing special, it only contains numerical (float) values for each polygon.
